# WebRTC without actual audio / video device

Tags: c++, webrtc

I am planning (using native API), to establish webRTC session between two clients.
My requirement is to establish webRTC session without using PC's audio/video devices (as I plan to have multiple simultaneous webRTC sessions in same PC).

I am currently following [this](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started) tutorial and want to know where in these files the following things happen:

1. open the audio / video device
2. read from audio / video device (capture)
3. write to audio / video device (play)
4. close the audio device

Kindly guide me if somebody knows the file-name / function-name where I need to look for above 4 points.

Comment: Capture and play are easy Look here: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

Without audio/video device seems unusual

Comment: Your question seems contradictory. Your requirement is to **not** use audio/video devices but below you ask how to do so. It is indeed possible to send and receive media streams which are not captured by the camera/microphone. Search for the web audio api, especially for the [`mediaStreamDestination`](http://w3.org/TR/webaudio/#MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode). This way you can send the audio processed by the audio api to your peer.

Comment: MarijnS95, My question is to know where in code audio/video device is opened, so that I will comment that part of code. Are you saying that without modifying code, I can bypass audio/video device opening/closing/capturing/playing. For capturing operation I would like to read from file, for play I would like to write to a file.

Comment: @Kamal Inside which code do you want to know where you can find these functions? When I look up webrtc native api I can only find an api for browser makers. If you are just writing your script yourself, you shouldn't add the streams. As you say about files, you'd better use data channels. Remember those still have some bandwidth limits. And actually, yes. If you are not using any library for webrtc and just write everything yourself, you can easily bypass the adding of video/audio.

Comment: @MarijnS95 I am right now looking in native peerconnection example (it has both client and server). Today peerconnection client captures video/audio and send to remote peerconnection client which plays it in a custom GUI (not browser). My first effort is instead of sending captured media to remote peerconnection client just send the media read from a file.

Comment: I have not yet found the example (maybe you have a link?). If you chose the peer connection it is like streaming the prerecorded media, whereas data channels can transport raw data. In JavaScript you get the media by using `getUserMedia`, add the media to the rtc stream by calling `.addStream`, and get the media on the client by the event handler `onaddstream`. I don't think this is helpful for the example but that is the direction you should look at.

Comment: @MarijnS95 Thanks. You can check http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started and search for "Setting up P2P calls between peerconnection_clients". Here the code is in C++ (not java script). Though I am not sure, will try to find equivalent of getUserMedia etc.

Comment: @Kamal I have actually never coded in C++ (although I would want to do after my exams). While searching the files, I found something about video rendering in [main_wnd.cc](http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/talk/examples/peerconnection/client/main_wnd.cc). Maybe the camera 'getting' something to do with that. I suggest you to add the C++ tag to your question as this is C++ related (as this was not clear from the initial question).